# How to escape single quote for a prop?

Tags: django, vue.js, django-templates, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a Django context variable which is a jsonified list of strings but some of those strings might have a single quote '

```
import json
list_of_strings = ["test", "hello", "I have a'single quote"]
return render(request, 'template.html', {
    'strings': json.dumps(list_of_strings)
})
```

Then I insert it into a vue component through one of his props which, as you can see, must be wrapped between single quotes.

`:strings='{{ strings|safe }`}'

But it crashes, just insert the list until the first single quote and then writes everything else as text in the browser.

How can I escape it?

Comment: I don't know anything about vue.js but are you sure it can only work with single quotes?

Comment: With double quotes I have the opposite issue, the prop reads everything until the first " then renders as text the rest of the list

Comment: And how do you expect the `strings` variable to be at the end when `vue` reads it?

Comment: [Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

Comment: @nik_m it is an array, like (3) ["test", "hello", "I have a'single quote"], I mean, it's working already if an item of they array hasnt a single quote

Comment: @RoyJ mm ok, but it works like that, but then which is the alternative to send data through the prop? with v-bind or v-prep wont work

Comment: Are you using Vue 1 or 2?

Comment: It's not clear to me where and how `strings` is being injected into your code. I think that's **nik_m**'s question as well. What does the HTML of the component use look like?

Comment: The strings end looking something messing like this ="" test, "cro\u00fbte=", =""

Comment: If I just "print" the array it looks like this ["test", "hello", "I have a\\'single quote"]

Comment: Ok I fixed it, it was a Django issue, I have to use |escape instead |safe

Comment: or you can try using string literals for vue.js

Answer (score 4):

This works fine. If the array is being used as a variable, simply `v-bind` the variable name. if the array is being injected into the component instantiation, you would need to replace single quotes with backslash-single quotes.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    list_of_strings: ["test", "hello", "I have a'single quote"]
  },
  components: {
    showString: {
      props: ['strings']
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <show-string :strings="list_of_strings" inline-template>
    <div>
      <div v-for="s in strings">{{s}}</div>
      <div v-for="s in ['some', 'array', 'single\'quote']">{{s}}</div>
    </div>
  </show-string>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Roy J's answer is correct, but in case it is not obvious to others you need to assign the json to a javascript variable and then pass it to `v-bind`.

eg

```
<script>
var list_of_strings = {{ list_of_strings|safe }};
</script>

<my-component v-bind:strings="list_of_strings"></my-component>
```